# APK download works with Dolphin but not stock browser

Tags: android, nginx, apk

I am making a corporate android application that we need to install via URL (no play store).  I have it hosted at /latest.apk .  I have nginx settings forcing

Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="latest.apk"

When I download the apk onto a phone with the stock web browser and try to open it, I get "Can't open file" error.  However, when I download with Dolphin, it opens just fine.  Does anyone know why this is?  PLEASE do NOT respond with "play store", "file browser", or "apk installer app" related answers.  This is about installing an apk via a url without any 3rd party apps.